# Image not loading, but not firing onerror or onabort

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm downloading a large number of images and it happens that from time to time, an image "escapes" the script without firing any of these events (unfortunately I don't have an actual example image):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function() {alert("error")};
img.onabort = function() {alert("abort")};
img.onload = function() {alert("success")};
img.src = whateverurl;
```

Is there any other event that might be fired by a timeout or any other thing that might cause the image not to load?

Comment: What does your console say? Any errors?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#event-xhr-loadstart Maybe it fired a timeout...

Comment: @putvande Nothing in the console.

Comment: @miguel-svq Does that document mean that an `ontimeout` event exists? I've added it but nothing changes.

Comment: Not in img, it's in the request itself. There is where you can place the timeout callback if you load them via AJAX. Anyway take a look to the "inspector" to see what is going on with your request (F12!).

Comment: @miguel-svq Nothing strange in the inspector. If I switch from `img.src` to AJAX, will there be any cross-domain issues?

Comment: Probably, if the images are not in your server. Enyway the problem can somewhere else. Post a bigger "picture" of the code, maybe someone find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with different web browsers in similar situation (downloading many images) and ran into several problems. So, my answer will not solve your problem, but maybe you get some inspirations.

**The New Ipad** can not load two images at the same time, period. This is disaster, because if one of my images is stuck on the server side, the whole app stucks. If I'm trying more images at a time, the browser schedules it. Even worse, I can detect timeout (I start a `setTimeout()` when setting `.src` of the image, and if `setTimeout()` comes before `.onload()` and `.onerror()`, I know that there's a stuck on server side, but as far as I know, there is no way to cancel image download. Setting `.src`, deleting object, removing from DOM - none cancels.

**Write a proxy** for monitoring image downloads. I've written a primitive one in PHP, and modified client-side code to use it with images, e.g. instead of `example.net/pics/image3.png` I've used `local/myproxy.php?img=example.net/pics/image3.png`. The proxy

- logs img download begin
- fethces image from the server and provides it
- then logs img download end

During examining logs, I've used "ops!" phrase often. Slow image "download end" log messages appears long seconds after requesting them, and other strange behaviors guaranteed.

There is one advice I can recommend: **get control of scheduling image downloads**. As New iPad tought me, the best practice is to limit pending image downloads to 1. I don't like it, most desktop browsers can download images on multiple threads, I've read that 2 images at a time from the same domain, 4..8 images for the same page.

Good luck.